# Emacs (TeX): how to search and replace a whole region?

Tags: regex, emacs, replace, tex

I bother you to have some tips for this problem: I'm working in Latex with a very dirty code, generated by [writer2latex](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/) (quite good programme, anyway) and, using Emacs, I'm trying to query-replace multiple lines of code, for instance:

```
{\centering   [Warning: Image ignored] % Unhandled or unsupported graphics:
%\includegraphics[width=11.104cm,height=8.23cm]{img34}
```

have to become:

```
\begin{figure}[tpb]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{img34}
```

Using M-x re-builder, I found out that I could underline the whole region I need to query-replace with the string: `\{.*centering.*`[c-q](/questions/tagged/c-q)[c-j](/questions/tagged/c-j)`.*cm]` but, if I M-x replace-regexp using this, I only get: `Invalid regexp: "Invalid content of \\{\\}"`
Any suggestion about how to perform the query? I have a HUGE amount of lines like these to replace... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error message because in Emacs' regular expressions the curly braces`\{` and `\}` have special meaning. These braces are used to specify that the part of the regexp immediately before the braces should be matched a certain number of times.

From the GNU Emacs [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#Regexps) on regexps:

> \{n\}
>       is a postfix operator specifying n repetitions [...]
>
> \{n,m\}
>       is a postfix operator specifying between n and m repetitions [...]

If you want your regexp to actually match a curly brace, do not escape it with a leading slash:

`{.*centering.*`<kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>`.*cm]`

In order to use a backslash in the replacement string you have to escape it with another backslash. (When doing this in code, it quickly becomes quite ugly because inside a double-quoted string backslashes themselves have to be escaped already. However, since you are doing your replacements interactively, the double escaping is not necessary and thus two backslashs are enough.)

<kbd>M-C-%</kbd> `{.*centering.*`<kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>`.*cm]` <kbd>RET</kbd> `\\begin{figure}[tpb]`<kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>`\\begin{center}`<kbd>C-q C-j</kbd>`\\includegraphics[width=\\textwidth]` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, perfect to select the region, but I can replace only using a text string without any "\" and "{", and I need them in Latex! Any suggestion? ThanX

Comment: Curly braces are not a problem in the replacement string, but backslashs have to be escaped. I've updated my answer accordingly. If it works for you, please remember to mark the answer as "correct". Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! You saved a filthy newbie :-P

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the re-syntax is "read", <kbd>C-c tab</kbd>.  Remove the initial backslash.  Now the regexp should work if you yank it into `replace-regexp`

Comment: I did: M-x re-builder, C-c TAB, I got: "Select syntax: read". I need to have in my query also "\" and "{" because they are very important for Latex...